# Поиск в строке с переводом строк

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка

`"qwe [slash n]
rty"`

```
var_dump(preg_match('/q.*y/s', $str));
```

Возвращает `int(0)`.
Пробовал вместо `.` ставить `\s`.
Положительного результата не получил.

Comment: Начнем с того, что это одна строка. "qwe<br> rty"

Но в любом случае даже без /s оно должно работать.


    php -r '$str = "qwe<br> rty"; var_dump(preg_match("/q.*y/s", $str));'
    int(1)

Проверьте, что у вас в $str.

Comment: я написал на 2х строчках. $str есть перевод строки.

Comment: То есть `$str="\n"` ?  
    
    $str="d\nsfsqfgwgy\nsg";
    var_dump(preg_match('/q.*y/s', $str));
    >> int(1)

Answer (score 1):

> **m (PCRE_MULTILINE)**
>
> По умолчанию PCRE обрабатывает данные как однострочную символьную строку (даже если она содержит несколько разделителей строк).

[Модификаторы шаблонов](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).